# Guava tree pruning

Tags: pruning, guavas

I pruned my 10 year old Guava tree to half the size in June 2018.  I am worried as it doesn't produce new shoots yet.This is Septemeber.

My question is about how long I have to wait to see new leaves?

Comment: Is it growing inside or outside?  How about a picture?